# XML element not bound

Tags: xml, adfs

I received this matadata file to import into ADFS, but I keep getting an error: 4:  108 The prefix "md" for element "md:EntityDescriptor" is not bound.

I have looked over the document, and searched the web high and low, and still cannot find an answer that fixes it for me. Here is the sample code with the certs and contact information removed:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="_63bb4679460ce67f883efc407ff14172e3472007" entityID="https://1502.censis.net/sso">
<md:Extensions>
    <alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512"/>
    <alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#sha384"/>
    <alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#sha224"/>
    <alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha512"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha384"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha224"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha384"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmldsig11#dsa-sha256"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha1"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <alg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>
</md:Extensions>
<md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol">
    <md:Extensions>
        <init:RequestInitiator Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:request-init" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/Login"/>
        <idpdisc:DiscoveryResponse Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/Login" index="1"/>
    </md:Extensions>
    <md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#aes128-gcm"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#aes192-gcm"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#aes256-gcm"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes192-cbc"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#rsa-oaep"/>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/Artifact/SOAP" index="1"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SLO/SOAP"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SLO/Redirect"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SLO/POST"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SLO/Artifact"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST" index="1"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign" index="2"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact" index="3"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/ECP" index="4"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/POST" index="5"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01" Location="https://1502.censis.net/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/Artifact" index="6"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the namespace prefixes are bound to a namespace uri. If you bound "md" to a uri (like `xmlns:md="md namespace uri"`) you'd get errors for "alg" not being bound.

From the spec ([4 Qualified Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-qualnames)):

> The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the qualified name,
>   and MUST be associated with a namespace URI reference in a namespace
>   declaration.

There is a lot more information in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/

If you're receiving this XML from someone else, you should let them know that the XML is not well-formed.